# Aggregating JSON responses after iterate in wso2

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am making 2 api calls inside iterate and want to aggregate all the json responses i get after the iterations and use that further. Although the payload forms correctly inside the iterate, once i try to aggregate it just returns `<jsonObject />`. The responses don't show up under the root element. Needed help to understand this issue and solve it.
This is the proxy i'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="TestProxy" startOnLoad="true" transports="http https vfs" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <property name="contentType" scope="transport" type="STRING" value="text/csv"/>
            <smooks config-key="smooksConf">
                <input type="text"/>
                <output type="xml"/>
            </smooks>
            <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
            
            <property expression="get-property('Credentials')" name="CREDENTIALS" scope="default" type="OM" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:ns3="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"/>
            <property expression="$ctx:CREDENTIALS//*[local-name()='TOKEN']" name="TOKEN" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            
            
            <iterate continueParent="true" expression="//Parents/parent" id="Iterate-over-json" sequential="true" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd">
                <target>
                    <sequence>
                        <property expression="json-eval($.parent.id)" name="parentId" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                        <call>
                            <endpoint>
                                <http method="get" uri-template="{{api-1}}">
                                    <suspendOnFailure>
                                        <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                                        <progressionFactor>-1</progressionFactor>
                                        <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
                                    </suspendOnFailure>
                                    <markForSuspension>
                                        <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                                    </markForSuspension>
                                </http>
                            </endpoint>
                        </call>
                        <property expression="json-eval($.data.id)" name="SourceNumber" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                        <property expression="json-eval($.data.name)" name="Name" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                        <property expression="json-eval($.data.parent_id)" name="SourceParentNumber" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                        <property expression="json-eval($.data.is_visible)" name="isActive" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                        <call>
                            <endpoint>
                                <http method="get" uri-template="{{api-2}}">
                                    <suspendOnFailure>
                                        <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                                        <progressionFactor>-1</progressionFactor>
                                        <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
                                    </suspendOnFailure>
                                    <markForSuspension>
                                        <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                                    </markForSuspension>
                                </http>
                            </endpoint>
                        </call>
                        <property expression="json-eval($.data[0].date_created)" name="create_date" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                        <property expression="json-eval($.data[0].date_modified)" name="modified_date" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                        <property expression="json-eval($.data[0].flag)" name="DateFlag" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                        
                        <filter regex="true" source="get-property('isActive')">
                            <then>
                                <property name="EndDate" scope="default" type="STRING" value=""/>
                                <property name="Active" scope="default" type="STRING" value="TRUE"/>
                            </then>
                            <else>
                                <property expression="get-property('modified_date')" name="EndDate" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                                <property name="Active" scope="default" type="STRING" value="FALSE"/>
                            </else>
                        </filter>
                        <filter regex="valid" source="get-property('DateFlag')">
                            <then>
                                <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                                    <format>
                                        {
                                    "SourceNumber" : "$1",
                                    "Name" : "$2",
                                    "SourceParentNumber" : "$3",
                                    "DateCreated" : "$4",
                                    "DateLastModified" : "$5",
                                    "Active" : "$6"
                                    }
                                    </format>
                                    <args>
                                        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:SourceNumber"/>
                                        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:Name"/>
                                        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:SourceParentNumber"/>
                                        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:CreatedDate"/>
                                        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:ModifiedDate"/>
                                        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:Active"/>
                                    </args>
                                </payloadFactory>
                                
                            </then>
                            <else>
                                <drop/>
                            </else>
                        </filter>
                    </sequence>
                </target>
            </iterate>
            <aggregate id="Iterate-over-json">
                <completeCondition>
                    <messageCount max="-1" min="-1"/>
                </completeCondition>
                <onComplete aggregateElementType="root" expression="json-eval($)">
                    <property expression="$body/*" name="response" scope="operation" type="OM"/>
                </onComplete>
            </aggregate>
            <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                <format>$1</format>
                <args>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('operation','response')"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
            <log>
                <property expression="$body/*" name="Aggregated-response"/>
            </log>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.Streaming">true</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">15</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.MaxRetryCount">1</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">sftp://{{sftp_path}}</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/plain</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure">sftp://{{sftp_path}}</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*.csv</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">sftp://{{sftp_path}}</parameter>
</proxy>
```

The response i get:

```
Aggregated-response = <jsonObject />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is you are continuing the flow after the Iteration is called which will result in two flows, one after calling the Iterate and one after the aggregation completes. Hence try setting the `continueParent="false"` in your iteration.

```xml
<iterate continueParent="false" expression="//Parents/parent" id="Iterate-over-json" sequential="true" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd">
.
.
.
.
</iterate>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I changed continueParent="false" but it did not work.

Comment: @Miley Can you add a log in the onComplete block and see what's being logged? If you can simplify the code so we can reproduce the issue it would help us to provide a better answer.

Comment: Facing similar issue...Have tried this solution, I put a log inside the onComplete block but it doesn't even get logged.